# Favoriting an answer

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

So, I already searched this site and found my [original question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2007/8671) (that is, the question I wanted to ask), which is, can we favorite an answer?  The answer is no, you can favorite a question.

So, I am here with a feature request of favoriting an answer.

If I favorite a question, it does keep track of the question in my favorites, but it gives credit to the question asker.  However, I often find nice answers, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/192839/8671), to questions that aren't that exciting and I favorite the question to keep track of that nice answer.  There are even badges that depend on how often a question is favorited.  We could easily have similar badges for answers that are favorited and then people can actually give credit where they want.  I don't have to upvote a question because I like an answer to it.  I upvote the answer itself.

Or, imagine a question with many answers and I really like 3 of them.  I would like to catalog these various wonderful answers as my favorites, not just favorite the question once.  When I look at a favorite question later, I can't really tell why I favorited it.  I might have to scroll through the question and all answers to figure out why I favorited it.  And, then, I might only see 1 of the nice answers (without spending a lot of time looking through all answers) and assume that's why I favorited it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/marking-an-answer-as-favorite

Comment: I've closed the old question @Jonas linked to as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Perhaps I can favorite the question, upvote the answers I like, and downvote the question to even out the fact that I favorited it :)

Comment: "And, then, I might only see 1 of the nice answers (without spending a lot of time looking through all answers) and assume that's why I favorited it."  If the answer is good, usually one will have upvote it and this gives a quite strong visual indication. Thus the answers one found good are easily distinguishable from other answers. Questions with that many answers that this is not easlly sufficient are first very rare and second likely too broad.

Comment: It is not exactly the same as favorites, but the new feature for following posts can be used for answers (and for questions). For more details see [the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info), [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661),  [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994#31406), etc.